# MBL_349876.UNOFFICIAL FOUND

Tags: cpanel

I use CPanel to upload html and filezilla for FTP.
The problems when I upload the file 'index.php' are:

```
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <!--/***************LIBRERIE JS,CSS************/ -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <!--/******************************************/ -->

<!--INDICIZZAZIONE GOOGLE -->
<META NAME="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="infissi sardegna, infissi alluminio, aretino, serramenti, aretino serramenti, infissi sardegna, infissi cagliari, aretino cagliari,Infissi sardegna, infissi, infissi, finestre, finestre PVC">
<META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="Aretino Serramenti, Leader costruzione e vendita di infissi in tutta la Sardegna.">
<div id="description_hidden">Aretino Serramenti, Leader costruzione e vendita di infissi in tutta la Sardegna.(Aretino, serramenti, infissi cagliari, Infissi sardegna, infissi, infissi, finestre, finestre PVC, FINESTRE LEGNO, infissi pvc, infissi pvc cagliari.)</div>
<img src="images/description.jpg" alt="Aretino Serramenti, Leader costruzione e vendita di infissi in tutta la Sardegna.(Aretino, serramenti, infissi cagliari, Infissi sardegna, infissi, infissi, finestre, finestre PVC, FINESTRE LEGNO, infissi pvc, infissi pvc cagliari.)"/>


<div id="fb-root"></div>
<?php
/*******Copyrigth YourWW*******/

$m = $_GET['m'];
echo '<head>';
echo '<title>Aretino Serramenti di Armando Aretino</title>';

echo '</head>';
/*******HEADER********/
include('header.php');

/*******COPERTINA********/
echo '<div id="copertina">';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div id="under_cop">
<div id="container_under_cop">
<span class="font_under_cop">
COSTRUZIONE SU MISURA MADE IN SARDEGNA
CON 25 ANNI DI ESPERIENZA NEL SETTORE DEI SERRAMENTI IN PVC</span>
';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
switch($m){
    default:
    /*******MAIN********/

echo '<div class="main">';
echo'<div id="up_main"><span class="font_up_main">';
echo"AMPIA GAMMA DI FORME E COLORI - QUALITA' DEI MATERIALI E ATTENZIONE AI PARTICOLARI - ASSISTENZA TECNICA E DI PROGETTO - CONSEGNA
MONTAGGIO E ASSISTENZA POST VENDITA - RISPARMIO ENERGETICO - RISPARMIO SULLA MANUTENZIONE - PREVENTIVI GRATUITI";
echo'</span></div>';
include('main.php');
echo '</div>';
    break;


case'home':
    /*******MAIN********/
echo '<div class="main">';
echo '<div class="main">';
echo'<div id="up_main"><span class="font_up_main">';
echo"AMPIA GAMMA DI FORME E COLORI - QUALITA' DEI MATERIALI E ATTENZIONE AI PARTICOLARI - ASSISTENZA TECNICA E DI PROGETTO - CONSEGNA
MONTAGGIO E ASSISTENZA POST VENDITA - RISPARMIO ENERGETICO - RISPARMIO SULLA MANUTENZIONE - PREVENTIVI GRATUITI";
echo'</span></div>';
include('main.php');
echo '</div>';
    break;
include('main.php');

echo '</div>';
    break;

case 'inostrilavori':
echo '<div id="main_long">';
echo'<div id="up_main"><span class="font_up_main">';
echo"AMPIA GAMMA DI FORME E COLORI - QUALITA' DEI MATERIALI E ATTENZIONE AI PARTICOLARI - ASSISTENZA TECNICA E DI PROGETTO - CONSEGNA
MONTAGGIO E ASSISTENZA POST VENDITA - RISPARMIO ENERGETICO - RISPARMIO SULLA MANUTENZIONE - PREVENTIVI GRATUITI";
echo'</span></div>';
    include('gallery.php');
    echo '</div>';
    break;


    case 'contatti':
echo '<div class="main">';
echo'<div id="up_main"><span class="font_up_main">';
echo"AMPIA GAMMA DI FORME E COLORI - QUALITA' DEI MATERIALI E ATTENZIONE AI PARTICOLARI - ASSISTENZA TECNICA E DI PROGETTO - CONSEGNA
MONTAGGIO E ASSISTENZA POST VENDITA - RISPARMIO ENERGETICO - RISPARMIO SULLA MANUTENZIONE - PREVENTIVI GRATUITI";
echo'</span></div>';
    include('contatti.php');
    echo '</div>';
    break;
}
/*******FOOTER********/
echo '<div id="footer">
<div id="container_footer">
<span class="font_footer">ARETINO SERRAMENTI<br/>
Via Roma 264, Ussana (CA) - Tel: 328 222 4802<br/>
e-mail: info@aretinoserramenti.it</span>';
echo '</div>';
echo'<div id="facebook">';
echo'<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Aretino-Serramenti/288686627886431?fref=ts" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<body>';

echo '</body>';


?>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=339320619516879";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>






Virus Detected; File not Uploaded! (MBL_349876.UNOFFICIAL FOUND)
```

Comment: It happends the same to me...
I'm using netsons hosting service, I tried also with the cpanel tool to upload the index.php but it find a virus. I use Bitdefender Total Security 2013 on my pc and it doesn't find anything in the files.

Comment: Same here with Mailrelays using Sanesecurity - all messages were detected as infected - I've takenb Clamav out of the config until they solve it (hopefully soon!)

Comment: Same thing for my website: http://ginho.it. I use netsons and I thinks is its fault.
I hope they'll fix it as quickly as possible. Damn.

Answer (score 0):

ClamAV detected virus = [MBL_349876.UNOFFICIAL]:

We are using CXS / ClamAV  On our server which shows our 500 sites are infected ,
Most probably it`s a false Positive Error.

We checked our users using maldet and http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results
Both shows sites are clean .

Answer (score 0):

It is a wrong signature that happens to block basically everything... I have deleted it locally and hope they will re-release soon.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to us as well with customers legitimate e-mail.  We are using Amavis / ClamAV.  I have created a temporary rule in amavisd.conf to allow this signature to pass through for now:

@virus_name_to_spam_score_maps =
  (new_RE(
    [ qr'MBL_349876.UNOFFICIAL'                             => -10.0 ],
));

Answer (score 0):

My mail server would send dozens off alerts about this.

`MBL_349876.UNOFFICIAL`

it seems to be a signature mistake where any match to `://` will cause a false positive.  To solve this, we commented sources on `/etc/clamav-unofficial-sigs`